# ngModel passed through wrapper to child directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

Let's imagine, we have one child directive `<child/>`, that takes `ng-model` and `ng-change` and does some actions with them. And we have two kind of wrappers `<w1/>` and `<w2/>`, that contain `<child/>`.

- W1 should pass ng-model through directly to `<child/>`
- W2 should pass some inner object as model to `<child/>`

in first case i would use `require: '^ngModel'`
in second : `require: 'ngModel'` but i need them to work simultaneously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so model is simple object that can be passed easily through.

`<wrapper ng-model="foo"></wrapper>`

Wrapper:

```
module
.directive('wrapper', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<child ng-model='ngModel'></child>",
        scope: {
            ngModel:'='
        },
        link: function ($scope) {
        }
    };
});
```

Child:

```
module
    .directive('child', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: 'ngModel',
            template: "<div>some wierd stuff</div>",
            scope: {
            },
            link: function ($scope, iElem, iAttr, ngModel) {
                var a = ngModel.$viewValue;
            }
        };
    });
```